# Movement of a gyroscope with non-fixed axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

Assume one has a gyroscope rotating around an axis with both ends leaning on a dedicated semiplane as shown on the picture below. There is no friction either between the rotor and the axis or between the axis and the semiplanes. The only force is the gravity acting on the rotor.

How will the gyroscope behave if one instantly removes one of the semiplanes?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Also, have you ever done this with a bicycle wheel - it's very easy to try and well worth doing if you haven't. You might also look to the [Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)) as their qualitative behaviour is easy to understand in this situation - recall that these equations are written for a frame that moves with your bicycle wheel.